# How to add custom fields in devise invitables in rails the custom fields is your name and phone number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

Actually Ineed the exact code for this problem, I am working on it but face errors on it

Answer (score 0):

From [README](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#strong-parameters-)

Here is an example of what your application controller might need to include in order to add these parameters to the invitation view:

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters

  protected

  # Permit the new params here.
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:invite, keys: %i[name phone])
  end
end
```

Here is an example setting a User's name and phone for a custom invitation:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: invitation_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>
  <% resource.class.invite_key_fields.each do |field| -%>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label field %>
      <%= f.text_field field %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone %>
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit t("devise.invitations.new.submit_button") %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```